# Tic Tac Toe Game Status not updating

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a tic tac toe game which prints X and O to the buttons in the JFrame. Also those X and O are placed in arrays that are the virtual Board. When I call the check winner on the virtual Board the hasWon changes to true. But in the main method, that hasn't updated. How can I fix that? I have edited the code. Now, the program runs and at the end it asks the user if you want to play again. After that the board resets, but i right after I click once, the dialog box pops up again saying I've won.

```
//TicTacToe Class
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToe implements ActionListener
{
JFrame window = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
JButton button[] = new JButton[10];
int count = 0;
public static String letter;
JPanel board = new JPanel();
JMenuBar jmb;
JMenuBar status;
JMenu game;
JMenuItem nGame, notes, exit;
boolean won = false;
public String[] vBoard = new String[10];
String letterWin;
boolean keepPlaying = true;
JLabel label1;
Players player;
String winner;

public TicTacToe()
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Player 1 Enter your name:");
    String name1 = in.next();
    System.out.println("Player 2 Enter your name:");
    String name2 = in.next();
    player = new Players(name1, name2);
    window.setSize(500, 500);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    jmb = new JMenuBar();
    status = new JMenuBar();
    window.setJMenuBar(jmb);
    game = new JMenu("Game Options");
    jmb.add(game);
    JMenuItem notes = new JMenuItem("Instructions");
    notes.addActionListener(this);
    game.add(notes);
    game.addSeparator();
    JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    exit.addActionListener(this);
    game.add(exit);
    game.addSeparator();

    board.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
    board.setBackground(Color.black);
    for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++)
    {  
        button[k] = new JButton();
        window.add(button[k]);
        button[k].setBackground(Color.blue);
        button[k].addActionListener(this);
        board.add(button[k]);
    }

    window.add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    {    count++;
        if (count % 2 == 1)
            letter = "X";
        else letter = "O";

        for ( int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
        {

            if (e.getSource() == button[i])

            {   if(letter.equals("X"))
                    button[i].setBackground(Color.red);
                else if(letter.equals("O"))
                    button[i].setBackground(Color.white);
                button[i].setText(letter);
                button[i].setForeground(Color.black);
                button[i].setEnabled(false);
                vBoard[i] = letter;
                {   
                    if(vBoard[0].equals(vBoard[1]) && vBoard[1].equals(vBoard[2]) && (vBoard[2] != ""))
                        won = true;
                    else if(vBoard[3].equals(vBoard[4]) && vBoard[4].equals(vBoard[5]) && (vBoard[5] != ""))
                        won = true;
                    else if(vBoard[6].equals(vBoard[7]) && vBoard[7].equals(vBoard[8]) && (vBoard[8] != ""))
                        won = true;
                    else if(vBoard[0].equals(vBoard[3]) && vBoard[3].equals(vBoard[6]) && (vBoard[6] != ""))
                        won = true;
                    else if(vBoard[1].equals(vBoard[4]) && vBoard[4].equals(vBoard[7]) && (vBoard[7] != ""))
                        won = true;
                    else if(vBoard[2].equals(vBoard[5]) && vBoard[5].equals(vBoard[6]) && (vBoard[6] != ""))
                        won = true;
                    else if(vBoard[0].equals(vBoard[4]) && vBoard[4].equals(vBoard[8]) && (vBoard[8] != ""))
                        won = true;
                    else if(vBoard[2].equals(vBoard[4]) && vBoard[4].equals(vBoard[6]) && (vBoard[6] != ""))
                        won = true;
                    if(won == true && count <=9){

                        keepPlaying = false;
                        if(letter == "X")
                            winner = player.getPlayer1();
                        else winner = player.getPlayer2();
                    }
                    else if(won == false && count == 9)
                        winner = "No One";
 {    int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, winner + " has won!" + "\nDo you    want to start a new game?", 
                                "Winner", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                        if(option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                        {
                            keepPlaying = true;
                            count = 0;
                            won = false;
                            for(int l = 0; l <=9; l++)
                            {   button[l].setEnabled(true);
                                button[l].setText("");
                                button[l].setBackground(Color.blue);
                            }}
                        else if(option == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
                            System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }

        else if (e.getSource().equals("Exit"))
         {   int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to  exit?", 
                        "Exit Game", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                if(option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
                    System.exit(0);
                else if(option == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) 
                {   
                    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    window.add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    window.setJMenuBar(jmb);
                }
            }

            if(keepPlaying == false)
                for(int k = 0; k <=8; k++)
                    button[k].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
} 

//Players Class
public class Players
{
public Players(String name1, String name2)
{
    player1 = name1;
    player2 = name2;
    wins = 0;
    wins2 = 0;
}

public String getPlayer1()
{
    return player1;
}

public String getPlayer2()
{
    return player2;
}

public void addWin1()
{
    wins++;
}

public void addWin2()
{
    wins2++;
}

public int getP1Wins()
{
    return wins;
}

public int getP2Wins()
{
    return wins2;
}
public String player1, player2;
public static int wins, wins2;
}

//Main Class
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Game extends TicTacToe
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    TicTacToe board = new TicTacToe();  
}
public static String name1, name2;
}
```

Comment: Curiously, the part of the code which could be of interest for the question (the `checkWinner` implementation) is the only thing that you did not write up...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new variable named `hasWon` insade the main method of `Game` class

```
public class Game extends TicTacToe
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      //.....
      //Here you are creating new method level variable with same name as `hasWon`      
      boolean hasWon = board.getWin();
      //.....
    }
   public static String name1, name2;
   // This variable is never updated
   boolean hasWon;
}
```

You might want to do

```
Game game = new Game();
game.hasWon = board.getWin();
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
boolean hasWon = board.getWin();
```

to

```
hasWon = board.getWin();
```

and then add static to the `hasWon` variable declared outside the `main` method

Comment: You cant access non static variable from a static method without using a object reference.

Comment: The local variable masks the attribute but the attribute is not used anywhere, so while it is true that the code has bad style it does not affect the result. In short, the attribute is just unnecessary and can be safely deleted.